# meaning of hard labor

Tags: word-usage

Does "hard labor" always refer to physical labor in prison. or could it refer to any labor that's considered difficult?

For example, does "It's hard labor to read this book in its entirety" sound okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hard labour" means forced work for prisoners. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard%20labor):

> *compulsory labor of imprisoned criminals as a part of the prison discipline*

That said, people often refer to hard work that they're required to do as "hard labour".

In this sense, your example "It's hard labor to read this book in its entirety" would make sense if the whole book was required reading as part of a university course, and the book was long and/or difficult to read.

The labour is always something you didn't freely choose to do, and it always draws a metaphorical comparison to forced prison labour.